# How does boxplot in R calculate quantiles?

Tags: r, boxplot

Why 1st and 3rd quartiles don't match with boxplot in R?

```
a = c(3,12,15,16,16,17,19,34)
boxplot(a, horizontal = T)
range(a)
quantile(a) 
abline(v=quantile(a), lty=2)
```

[image]

@Henry:

```
abline(v=fivenum(a), col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to add `fivenum(a); abline(v=fivenum(a), col="green")` to the end of your code and see the effect

Comment: great! Outliers appears out of the range: quantile(a, c(1,3)/4) +/- 1.5*IQR(a) ??

Comment: @Juanchi the answer to the outliers question is *also* given by `?boxplot.stats` (by default, `coef` is 1.5, and the discussion of `coef` under the heading `Arguments` tells you what it does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `?boxplot.stats`:

> The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e.,
>   close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4). The hinges equal the quartiles for odd
>   n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n. Whereas the quartiles
>   only equal observations for n %% 4 == 1 (n = 1 mod 4), the hinges do
>   so additionally for n %% 4 == 2 (n = 2 mod 4), and are in the middle
>   of two observations otherwise.